# images/fonts in css, cssrewrite, dev environment, htaccess rewrite

Tags: php, symfony, mod-rewrite, assetic

In my Symfony test environment I want the dev-environment to be served without app_dev.php. This works, if I change .htacces to

```
# Rewrite all other queries to the front controller.
RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app_dev.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

But now, if I go to

```
http://xxx/test/
```

instead of

```
http://xxx/test/app_dev.php
```

all referenced images and fonts do use the wrong path. (a additional ../ due to the "app_dev.php/"-folder which is normally used). I did also the following:

```
php app/console ca:cl
php app/console assets:dump
php app/console assetic:install
```

What am I missing? Is another rewrite rule necessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the solution:

After comparing config_dev.yml with config.yml, I could see the parameter

```
use_controller: true
```

in the dev environment. It seems that this one is responsible, that in dev environment assets are loaded dynamically without dumping etc. Then I searched in Symfony's documentation for this one and found [Dumping Assets in Dev Env](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#dumping-asset-files-in-the-dev-environment)

After doing those steps, all referenced files were found.

Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 0):

try using this in .htaccess, use the cond match to your urls

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(img|files|images|favicon.ico|css|js|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app_dev.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work at all. The problem is not the rewrite condition (Symfony's htaccess recognizes if the file really exists and serves it) but the path assetic creates I suppose.